# Как получить тот же список сборок, что открывается в VS

Tags: c#

Как програмно загрузить список сборок, который открывается на вкладке Framework
[image: VS Framework tab]

и как загрузить список сборок, что отображается на вкладке Extensions
[image: VS Exstensions tab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как я понял задача сводится к тому, чтобы найти эти dll и получить, в одном случае все с маркером System, а в другом Microsoft.VisualStudio, вообще эти файлы копируются в GAC. От туда я бы их доставал вот так

```
static class Program
{

    private static string WindDir = "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\assembly\\GAC_MSIL";
    private static string ExtensionSystem = "C:\\ExtensionSystem";
    private static string ExtensionVS = "C:\\ExtensionVS";
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] directorys = Directory.GetDirectories(WindDir);
        Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\ExtensionSystem");
        Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\ExtensionVS");
        GetSystemExtension(directorys, "System.", ExtensionSystem);
        GetSystemExtension(directorys, "Microsoft.VisualStudio", ExtensionVS);
    }
    private static void GetSystemExtension(string[] directorys, string extension, string targedFolder)
    {
        foreach(string dir in directorys)
        {
            if ((dir.Contains(extension) && !dir.Contains("ProjectSystem") &&
               !dir.Contains("TypeSystem") && !dir.Contains("TeamSystem")) && 
               !dir.Contains(".resources")
               ||( Path.GetFileName(dir) == "System"))
            {
                string[] directorySystem = Directory.GetDirectories(Path.Combine(WindDir, dir));
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directorySystem[0]);
                File.Copy(files[0], Path.Combine(targedFolder, Path.GetFileName(files[0])));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

На сколько я понимаю это верно только для версии от .Net 4.0

Comment: В этом случае он так же вытягивает сборки ресурсов: .resources, а они не нужны

Comment: Ресурсы я поправил, но принцип все равно останется такой, вы сами можете внести нужные условия.

Comment: А если, к примеру в систему будут установлены доп компоненты вроде DevExpress, это опять фильтр менять?

Comment: Ну не менять, а добавлять , DevExpress тоже прописывается в GAC. Создайте еще папку под DevExp  и передайте в параметр "extension" - "DevExpress.", а в targetFolder - папку которую создали под DevExp